# Previous/Next Functionality like iOS mail app?

Tags: ios, swift, indexing, uiviewcontroller

I'm really close to figuring this out. So in the iOS mail app when you click on the two arrow keys it takes you to the previous/next mail. Its on the top right

[image: Screenshot]

I've managed to pass the indexPath value to my second `viewcontroller` and print in in the console. I can also increase and decrease from it.

```
if segue.identifier == "DetailVC" {
let detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailVC
let indexPath = self.collectionViewIBO.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.last!
detailVC.index = indexPath
}
```

**EDIT**
This is where I'm pulling the data from. It reads the values from my model. I cannot assign an indexPath to it however. I can only do that from the previous view controller

```
var monster: Monsters!
```

I've attempted to implement the "previous" functionality using this code. My view styling are in the `displayDataForIndexPath()` function and the function is called from my `view will appear`

```
@IBAction func monsPreviousIBO(_ sender: Any) {
    self.index = IndexPath(row: self.index.row - 1, section: self.index.section)
    displayDataForIndexPath()

}
```

But all it does is decrease the IndexPath. For some reason the data doesn't actually reload with my function. I'm missing some important puzzle piece here to achieving the same functionality.

**EDIT** The code in my `displayDataForIndex` is as follows

```
func displayDataForIndexPath() {

    if index.row == 0 {
        self.monsPreviousIBO.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    var monsterName = (String(format: "%03d", monster.speciesId!))
    self.navigationItem.title = monster.name!


    let gif = UIImage(gifName: monsterName)
    self.gifIBO.setGifImage(gif, manager: gifManager)
    gifIBO.contentMode = .center
    guard monster.legendary! != true else {
        // Value requirements not met, do something
        monsterStatusLegend()
        return
    }
    guard monster.subLegend! != true else {
        // Value requirements not met, do something
        monsterStatusSub()
        return
    }
    guard monster.isMega! != true else {
        // Value requirements not met, do something
        monsterStatusMega()
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: you should add the `displayDataForIndexPath()` code to answer your question. somehow you don't use the self.index variable while you execute the `displayDataForIndexPath()` function

Comment: Updated the post with added code. Hopefully that sheds some light on what I did wrong

Comment: note: index.row is it zero based?

Comment: you display all data depending on `monster` but you never change the `monster` depending which indexPath you used

Comment: @baxu - what is the `monsPreviousIBO` property? As far as I can tell the only thing happening in your `displayDataForIndexPath` method that has to do with the `indexPath` is that you're removing `monsPreviousIBO` from it's `superView` if the row is equal to zero.

Comment: I'm sorry what does that mean? _zero based?_ If you mean does the index start at 0 than yes.

Comment: What he's saying should fix your problem. Try something like `monster = monsters[index.row]` before you call `displayDataForIndexPath()` (assuming you have an array called "monsters")

Comment: ok - sorry my mistake. i dont reed the name of `monsPreviousIBO` - you just remove the previous button. but if you hit next then you need to display the previous again. better just disable the `monsPreviousIBO` in case of `row == 0`

Comment: @Pierce thanks for the help. Ive updated the post further to better explain. monster is a variable that reads from my model. I cannot subscript `index.row` to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you display all data depending on `monster` but you never change the `monster` depending which indexPath you used.

add some code to populate the `monster` from `indexPath`

```
monster = getMonster(index.row)
```

or in your case

```
@IBAction func monsPreviousIBO(_ sender: Any) {
    self.index = IndexPath(row: self.index.row - 1, section: self.index.section)
    monster = mons[self.index.row]
    displayDataForIndexPath()
}
```

or better in the `displayDataForIndexPath()` add this line:

```
func displayDataForIndexPath() {

    if index.row == 0 {
        self.monsPreviousIBO.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    monster = mons[self.index.row]

    //....
```

NOTE some suggestions:

- i would change the line for the button then it is enabled if the indexpath gets >0:

  ```
  self.monsPreviousIBO.isEnabled = (index.row != 0)
  ```
- just save the row as `monsterIndex = indexPath.row` and then deal only with the index and not indexPath.
- you don't need to save the current monster as monster if you use the monster only in `displayDataForIndexPath` - then you can get the current monster just there and have it a local variable in this function:

  ```
  var monster = mons[self.index.row]
  ```

Comment: Thanks to your help I was able to figure it out! Posted the answer in the OP. Could you add more detail to your answer to reflect what I put on the op so I can accept your post =)